# Extending decorators

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I was referring to the wikipedia article on decorator pattern and I found the [coffee making example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_example_.28coffee_making_scenario.29) really useful. What I found in most of the examples of decorator pattern, including the above one, is that the decorators don't add their own properties/methods other than modifying those defined in the contract. For example, the Milk class in the coffee making example simply 
override the methods (getCost() and getIngredients() ) defined in the Coffee contract. What if the Milk class wants to add its own methods,  GetBrand() or GetQuantity()  for example  (Note that clients may need to cast their interface to Milk class to access these methods) . While nothing stops you from adding fields/methods to decorators, my question here is that is it a good practice to add fields/methods to decorators other than what is agreed upon in the contract?

One solution that came into my mind is to add a Properties dictionary (any key value pair ) to the contract and each decorator can add their own properties to this dictionary. Later, clients can access the properties using their keys. The problem is that the collection could be empty for most of the classes. Also, I think

```
  milk.GetBrand()
```

is more readable than

```
  milk.Properties.PropertybyName[cs_cost].
```

Please share your opinions on this problem..

Thanking you all,

Pradeep

Comment: 'Solution' to a Decorator pattern can be very language specific, as different languages make it easy or difficult to implement this pattern. Are you looking for a solution in a specific language?

Comment: Not really...I am using C# though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intent of Decorator pattern: Attach additional responsibilities to an
>   object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to
>   subclassing for extending functionality.

So the clients of the decorator or the undecorated target has a need to see both of them through the same contract. Hence, adding more methods to a decorator does not provide any advantage when you use the "Decorator Pattern".

The term "decorator" however is used in very general sense as well (Not to refer to the Decorator pattern). So it's common for you to hear someone talking about a decorator that adds properties/methods to a class to decorate a target. However, it's not the Decorator pattern.